# How to get the current Item in swipe view

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I would like to get the current item in Swipe view but it is not working.

When Click on OnSwipeDelete the code stop I have error says : System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

It seems that I do not get the value of Mywords

Here is my Xaml code (My xaml code is in comment to be able to post on stackoverflow):

```
     <!--   
        <ListView x:Name="WordSList" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <custom:CustomViewCell SelectedItemBackgroundColor="White">
                <ViewCell.View >
                    <SwipeView>
                        <SwipeView.RightItems>  
                            <SwipeItems>
                         
                                <SwipeItem Text="Edit" BackgroundColor="#7D7D7D" ></SwipeItem>
                                <SwipeItem Text="Delete"   Invoked="OnSwipeDelete">BackgroundColor="Red"      ></SwipeItem>
        
                            </SwipeItems> 
        
                        </SwipeView.RightItems> 
        
                        <SwipeView.Content >  
                            <StackLayout >
        
                               
                                <Label TextColor="#7D7D7D" Text="{Binding Word1}"  FontSize="15" />
                            </StackLayout>  
                        </SwipeView.Content>  
        
                    </SwipeView>  
                </ViewCell.View>  
        
            </custom:CustomViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>  
 -->
```

Here is my C# code :

```
  private async void OnSwipeDelete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Get Item
            SwipeItemView item = sender as SwipeItemView;
            // Cas to MyWords
            MyWords mywordinfos = item.BindingContext as MyWords;


             // display the select word
            Console.WriteLine("See word " + mywordinfos.Word1);
        }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: where is `OnSwipeDelete` being assigned?

Comment: @Jason  I have updated

Comment: please define "not working".  When you debug it where does it go wrong?  if `WordSList` is an `IEnumerable<MyWords>` I would expect the code you have to work

Comment: @Jason When Click on OnSwipeDelete the code stop I have error says : System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'  It seems that I do not get the valu eof Mywords

Comment: that seems like a highly relevant piece of information that should have been included in your post, not in the fourth comment.  And given that, you need to use the debugger or look at the stack trace to identify the specific line causing the issue.  My guess is that casting `sender` to `SwipeItemView` is failing because sender is actually a `SwipeItem`, but I may be wrong.

Comment: The casting is not working. I get not value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235228/discussion-between-hko-and-jason).

Comment: you are casting to the wrong type.  Either use the debugger to figure out the correct type, or try using `SwipeItem`

Comment: WordSList is a List<MyWords> I do not know if there is another way to cast

Comment: you have two different casts in that method.  Which one is failing?

Comment: You are right I was doing the wrong casting. I should use SwipeItem; Now it is working. Thanks very much !

Comment: Glad you figured it out. If you add an "Answer" below, showing the code that works, that will help others.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the answer. Thanks Jason ;)

```
private async void OnSwipeDelete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SwipeItem item = sender as SwipeItem;
    var mywordinfos = item.BindingContext as MyWords;

}
```